# Flutter: Como puedo obtener la ubicacion de un usuario(latitud y longitud) sin una conexion a internet

Tags: flutter

Estaría muy agradecido si me orientan o si existe alguna libreria para poder lograr esto(las que revisé requieren una conexión a internet). Soy nuevo en flutter, gracias.

Comment: Para la geolocalización, según entiendo no debería ser obligatorio tener conexión, y puedes usar un plugin como este https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator.

Answer (score 1):

Acá puedes encontrar muchos paquetes o librerías que hacen lo que tú deseas y no necesitas conexión a internet.

https://pub.dev/packages?q=location